# gtag.js can't correctly send Enhanced eCommerce event to google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce, gtag.js

I use the `gtag.js` to send Enhanced eCommerce event to Google Analytics. I think Google Analytics actually gets all event from my demo web. But there are 3 type event was not shown at event table.

[image]

and the 3 events below:

- [Measure product impressions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/enhanced-ecommerce#measure_product_impressions)
- [Measure product detail views](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/enhanced-ecommerce#measure_product_detail_views)
- [Measure promotion impressions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/enhanced-ecommerce#measure_promotion_impressions)

And here is the sample code I used:

#### Measure product impressions

```
gtag('event', 'view_item_list', {
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "P12345",
      "name": "Android Warhol T-Shirt",
      "list_name": "Search Results",
      "brand": "Google",
      "category": "Apparel/T-Shirts",
      "variant": "Black",
      "list_position": 1,
      "quantity": 2,
      "price": 2
    },
    {
      "id": "P67890",
      "name": "Flame challenge TShirt",
      "list_name": "Search Results",
      "brand": "MyBrand",
      "category": "Apparel/T-Shirts",
      "variant": "Red",
      "list_position": 2,
      "quantity": 1,
      "price": 3
    }
  ]
});
```

#### Measure product detail views

```
gtag('event', 'view_item', {
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "P12345",
      "name": "Android Warhol T-Shirt",
      "list_name": "Search Results",
      "brand": "Google",
      "category": "Apparel/T-Shirts",
      "variant": "Black",
      "list_position": 1,
      "quantity": 2,
      "price": '2.0'
    }
  ]
});
```

#### Measure promotion impressions

```
gtag('event', 'view_promotion', {
  "promotions": [
    {
      "id": "abc123",
      "name": "summer_promo"
    },
    {
      "id": "xyz987",
      "name": "spring savings"
    }
  ]
});
```

I find that the commonality of these events is that they are all page load event. But I use click to trigger them. But I think it's also have to work.

That's so strange~ Somebody help me, please~

Comment: The events look good. Is the global snippet present on the pages in question? https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/devguide/snippet

Comment: That's right. 
However,I take a look at google analytics today, and I notice that the product impression and promotion impression was recorded  at Enhanced eCommerce table. so that's really work in google analytics. But it still can't show event at real-time table. strange~